# Not able to stop service using Handler in android

Tags: android, service, handler

I just start background service in Handler.now I want to stop Service but service not stopped from Handler and any other class.
**below is My Code:-**
**below is handler where i try to Start And Stop Service.**

```
mHandler = new Handler();
 mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
                                Log.e("mTrackStatus",String.valueOf(mTrackStatus));

                                if (mTrackStatus == 1) {
                                    Log.e("BACKGROUND=", "background Service Start");
                                    //handler will call after every 10 seconds
                                    context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);

                                } else if (mTrackStatus == 2) {
                                    Log.d("StopTracking", "StopTracking");
                                    context.stopService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));

                                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);

                                }

                            }
                        };
                        // mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);
                        mRunnable.run();
```

> I have tried Lot's Of method like
>    **1.** **context.stopService(new Intent(context,BackgroundService.class));** and   **stopSelf();** but it will not work for me

Comment: What is your mTrackStatus?

Comment: mTrackStatus is a variable to store track status from web api and corresponding to this  i am stopping the service but it doesn't work

Comment: it totally depends on your mTrackStatus  as you are checking it,try to remove condition of mTrackStatus and then start and stop the service ,if it succeeds then try to update mTrackStatus when ever required .

Comment: also, check whether context is null or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Spent 2 days on this problem. Finally i Solve the Issue.Actually My BackgrounService is Stop by using :-
**context.stopService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));**

I use onLocationChanged() method in My services class and when i Try to Stop Service, Service is Stopped but onLocationChanged() method is Continue sly running in Background. By using Stop Service Service is stop but onLocationChanged() is not Stopped because it Android Default method which we can not able stop that.